# Block completion handler reference is nil after completing background fetch

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, background-process

I am trying to implement a background fetch of an RSS Feed using performFetchWithCompletionHandler, but when I want to call the completion handler it's nil.

Am I missing a way to retain my reference to self.completionHandler?

Am I declaring self.completionHandler correctly?

in app delegate:

```
        //background fetch new RSS Feeds
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    MasterViewController *navigationController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MasterView"];
    MasterViewController *viewController = navigationController;

    [viewController startParsingWithCompletionHandler2: ^ (UIBackgroundFetchResult completionHandler2){
        completionHandler (UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
    }];
}
```

in main view controller:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) void (^completionHandler)(UIBackgroundFetchResult);


- (void) startParsingWithCompletionHandler2:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler2
{
    self.completionHandler = completionHandler2;
    if (self.completionHandler) {
        NSLog(@"completionHandler");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"not completionHandler");
    }
    [self performSelector: @selector(stopParsing) withObject: nil afterDelay: PARSER_TIME_LIMIT];
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    numberOfCompletedStories = 0;
    [self.parserArray removeAllObjects];
                                                        //check for RSS Site data updates
    for (int lCounter = 0; lCounter < self.rssFeedAddresses.count; lCounter ++) {
        RSSParser *parser = [[RSSParser alloc] init];
        [parser setDelegate: self];
        [self.parserArray addObject: parser];
        [parser setSiteTitle: [self.rssFeedNames objectAtIndex: lCounter]];
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(begin:) toTarget: parser withObject: [self.rssFeedAddresses objectAtIndex: lCounter]];
    }
    if (self.completionHandler) {
        NSLog(@"#2  completionHandler");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"#2  not completionHandler");
    }
}

    - (void) storyIsDone//called when parser completed one rss feed
{
    numberOfCompletedStories ++;
    if (self.completionHandler) {
        NSLog(@"storyIsDone  YES completion handler %i", numberOfCompletedStories);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"storyIsDone  Not completion handler");
    }
    if (numberOfCompletedStories == self.rssFeedAddresses.count)
    {
            //if all the feeds are done cancel time-out timer
        [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget: self selector: @selector(stopParsing) object: nil];
        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(reloadRSSfeeds) name: @"ReloadFeeds" object: nil];
        canRefresh = YES;
        NSLog(@"call back");
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(callCompletion) withObject: self waitUntilDone: YES];
    }//else not yet complete
}

- (void) callCompletion
{
    if (self.completionHandler) {
        NSLog(@"callCompletion  YES completion handler");
        self.completionHandler (UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

    }else{
        NSLog(@"callCompletion  Not completion handler");
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
completionHandler
 #2  completionHandler
storyIsDone  Not completion handler
storyIsDone  Not completion handler
storyIsDone  Not completion handler
storyIsDone  Not completion handler
storyIsDone  Not completion handler
storyIsDone  Not completion handler
storyIsDone  Not completion handler
call back
callCompletion  Not completion handler
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class not properly initialized

When using performFetchWithCompletionHandler for background fetch - methods are called in a different order resulting in some objects not being properly initialized.

When the app is launched in the foreground these methods are called: (in order)

initWithCoder
awakeFromNib
viewDidLoad
dispatchLoadingOperation
viewDidAppear

When performing a background fetch methods are called in the following order:

initWithCoder
awakeFromNib
startParsingWithCompletionHandler2
viewDidLoad
dispatchLoadingOperation
viewDidAppear

Of particular note: vieDidLoad was called before dispatchLoadingOperation which kicked off the parsing when running in foreground.

When running in background, startParsingWithCompletionHandler2 (which also kicks off parsing when running in background) was called before viewDidLoad.

Since several objects were initialized in viewDidLoad, the parsing was begun before expected and my array was not initialized to store my parsing results. This appeared to me that the app was not launching.

While I was looking at the call back for the completion handler being nil, the real issue was the Class not being setup properly.

Answer (score 0):

I always use `(nonatomic, copy)` for block properties. You might try that and see if it helps.

In your code, though, I think you can just pass through the completion handler that's passed into `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:`.

Comment: I need a reference to the completion handler because I receive a delegate callback to storyIsDone when parsing is complete.  It is there that I need to call self.completionHandler (UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData)

Comment: Do you know the difference between copy and strong?

Comment: I tried  @property ( copy) void (^completionHandler)(UIBackgroundFetchResult);
but self.completionHandler is still nil.

Answer (score 0):

In the .h file define a completion handler like this:

```
typedef void (^CompletionHandler)(UIBackgroundFetchResult BFR);
```

Also define your completion handler property like this:

```
@property (copy) CompletionHandler completionHandler;
```

Then in the .m file set it like this:

```
self.completionHandler = handler;
```

You need the `(copy)` keyword here so that the block which is passed through via the `startParsingWithCompletionHandler2:` method is copied and that copy is then retained by the main view controller.

From the docs:

> Note: You should specify copy as the property attribute, because a block needs to be copied to keep track of its captured state outside of the original scope. This isn’t something you need to worry about when using Automatic Reference Counting, as it will happen automatically, but it’s best practice for the property attribute to show the resultant behavior.

See [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)

EDIT:

I thought it would be good to add that you **MUSTN'T** call a completion handler (i.e. `completionHandler(/*someArgs*/)`) when the `completionHandler` is `nil`. If you do it will cause your App to crash.

To overcome this you can put in a simple check e.g.

```
!completionHandler ?: completionHandler(/*someArgs*/);
```

The above code is semantically equivalent to:

```
if (completionHandler != nil) {
    completionHandler(/*someArgs*/)
}
```

it just condenses it onto one line using the ternary operator.

Comment: What is: handler?  i.e.:  self.completionHandler = handler;  is that self.completionHandler = completionHandler2;

Comment: Yes it is the equivalent.

Comment: If this fixed the problem you can check it as the accepted answer.

Comment: P.S. See my edited answer for how to deal with nil blocks, it's pretty important if you're going to be using them in production code as nil blocks can cause your App to crash.

Comment: I added the suggested changes, but,  if (self.completionHandler) is always nil and I get the exact same output. :-(